# XPath href attributes value under both tag a and tag link

Tags: xpath, hyperlink

How Could I get all the href attributes under tag either a or link.

Say my html looks like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="www.a.com">Here</a>
    <link rel="name" href="www.b.com">
</div>
```

I know how to get those links separately but I want to know how to do them together in one go:

```
$x('//a/@href')
$x('//link/@href')
```

How to put them together? Something like:

```
$x('//tag in (a,link)/@href')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below **XPATH** will also work:

```
  /div//@href
```

**output**

```
www.a.com
www.b.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
//a/@href|//link/@href
```

The pipe (|) combines the 2 queries to one nodeset. (http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Since XPath 2 you can also use

```
(//a,//link)/@href
```

Or

```
div//(a,link)/@href
```